# How to get the confidence scores for the Google Cloud Vision API logo detection?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-apis-explorer

How can I find the probability or likelihood (confidence score) for the logo detection method of Google Vision API?

I have an image that gives these for the logo while none are correct. I want to use a threshold for it in terms of confidence score.

```
Logos:
Sogndal Fotball
Tequila Herradura
```

code:

```
# Performs logo detection on the image file
response_logo = client.logo_detection(image=image)
logos = response_logo.logo_annotations
print('Logos:')

for logo in logos:
    print(logo.description)

if response_logo.error.message:
    raise Exception(
        '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
        'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
            response_logo.error.message))
```

Comment: Are you getting wrong results constantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Performs logo detection on the image file
response_logo = client.logo_detection(image=image)
logos = response_logo.logo_annotations
print('Logos:')

logos_dict = {}
for logo in logos:
    print(logo.description)
    print('logo type: ', type(logo))
    print(logo)
    logos_dict.update({'logo': logo.description,
                       'logo_score': logo.score})

print(logos_dict)
```